# Iterate through LinkedHashSet with custom Object and remove items

Tags: android, linkedhashset

I have a custom Parcelable Object (ImageList) which is being filled with string names (test.jpeg) of picture files.

These objects are added to a LinkedHashSet.
The pictures are also saved in the internal storage of the device.

If the Application is closed, I want to **iterate** through the LinkedHashSet and remove all the items in it and at the same time delete the files associated with them on the internal storage.

Below is the code I have to iterate through the LinkedHashSet and remove/delete the items.

But it only processes the last item in the LinkedHashSet.

**The code is set in the onDestroy() method of the Main Activity**.

```
Iterator<ImageList> itr = imgList.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()) {

            File file = this.getFileStreamPath(itr.next().getImgName());
            file.delete();
            imgList.remove(itr.next());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are calling the `iter.next()` method twice inside of the loop. So you will get out of the list two different objects.

Even if the code would work in the first call `itr.next().getImgName()` you are retrieving one object and then in `imgList.remove(itr.next());` you retrieve another one which you delete. Effectively the object retrieved in `itr.next().getImgName()` is never deleted.

The second problem is that you are trying to use `imgList.remove(itr.next());` whilst processing the content of an iterator. This typically throws a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

To remove an element during iteration with an iterator you should use the iterator's `remove` method.

Here is a small example on how to remove elements correctly during an iterator based iteration in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    set.add("hi");
    set.add("there");
    Iterator<String> iter = set.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        String next = iter.next();
        System.out.println(next);
        iter.remove();
    }
    System.out.println(set.size());
}
```

If you run this code, this will print out:

```
hi
there
0
```

This is my suggestion for you to re-write the code:

```
Iterator<ImageList> itr = imgList.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    ImageList next = itr.next(); // Get the element from iterator
    File file = this.getFileStreamPath(next.getImgName());
    file.delete();
    itr.remove(); // Remove from collection using iterator
}
```

Comment: Many thx for the example and explanation gil! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Your iteration method is wrong. It will throw concurrent modification expection. while using iterator use inbuilt remove method from iterator to remove an item in underlying collection.(iterator.remove()) , iterator.next() will advance to next item. each call of next() should be associated with hasNext(). Any errors thrown while closing application?

use this example : http://www.java-examples.com/remove-element-collection-using-java-iterator-example